# How to compare all properties values from a two equal classes

Tags: class, comparison, structure

I've a class defined as follows:

```
Public Class DeviceConfig
    Private _maxNumCodesGlobal As Integer 
    Private _maxNumCodesDataMatrix As Integer 
    Private _maxNumCodesQR As Integer 
    Private _maxNumCodesBarcode As Integer 
    Private _partialResults As String 
    Private _allowIdenticalSymbols As String 
    Private _datamatrixValidation As Integer 
    Private _datamatrixValidationType
'AND MUCH MORE PROPERTIES
'GETTERS & SETTERS
End Class
```

as you can see it's a long list of properties in this class.

I need to compare the values of the properties from an instance with the values of the properties of another instance.

Is there a way to iterate through all of them, or even better, just comparing both classes and get true/false if they have the same properties values or not?

```
if instance1=instance2 then true
```

Thank you

Comment: You could write a class method that compares it to other objects of the same class, then you only need to write the comparison iteration logic once.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and created this method. Hopefully it will help you.
It uses reflections to iterate through the public fields, ignoring those with the JsonIgnore annotation. 
This method is not considering fields as List, Set, etc.
You can change it to work for properties instead of fields.

```
    protected <T> boolean equals(T object1, T object2) {
    Field[] fields = object1.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class)!= null) continue; //do not check the fields with JsonIgnore
        Object value1;
        Object value2;
        try {
            value1 = field.get(object1);
            value2 = field.get(object2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error comparing objects. Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        //comparing
        if (value1 == null) {
            if (value2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value1.equals(value2))
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```